# Can I series windings of separate transformers to increase the voltage rating of the whole?

Tags: transformer, series

I need a 1:1 transformer, 25VA 600VAC. I'm not having much luck finding such a thing. It occurs to me that I could take five smaller 1:1 120VAC transformers (like [this](http://www.signaltransformer.com/sites/all/pdf/241.pdf)), series all the primary windings and all the secondary windings, and get the same effect.

It seems to me that this is little different than taking a single multi-winding transformer and connecting its windings in different arrangements. Is this valid? Recommended? Are there problems?

Comment: I think your idea is valid but you might need balancing resistors, like when you use multiple series caps to increase the voltage rating. I'm not 100% sure though...

Comment: I am far from sure. I can imagine that working for two transformers (say across 240V) because the 'centre-connection' would be at a nominal zero volts, but 6 transformers make me feel nervous. Part of the cause of my nervousness is what is each transformer doing to the phase of the power. Would it all be in phase, and what happens if one is slightly out of phase? What happens with a reactive load? Two transformers look like a centre tap, and so seem simpler. However, I am definitely not an AC mains kind of guy.

Comment: @gbulmer I think that the phase thing would not be a problem, that's just like a big long single (mainly)inductive load.

Comment: @VladimirCravero - I am totally happy with the theory. However, I am less happy that actual manufactured products, especially ones with a high degree of mechanical manufacture, obey theory until I have parts in my hands, and I can measure them. I have never had a batch of transformers and measured them. I even *imagine* these things are within a usable tolerance. I am still conservative. IMHO, there are several things that might go wrong. I would want to test and measure before believing it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will work fine if they're connected properly (if they share voltage unevenly the one that gets more voltage will begin to saturate and the voltage across it will be limited).

However the transformers may not be sufficiently rated to be safe on 600VAC, so isolation and creepage distances may not be good enough to meet requirements. At least they're split-bobbin type which is inherently pretty good for isolation.

Since 600VAC is a common industrial voltage in Canada, there are a lot of control transformers available that will step down from 600VAC to 120VAC or 240VAC. I'd suggest using **two** of those transformers (600:120-> 120:600 or 600:240 -> 240:600) to get what you want.

For example, a Hammond B356633 is a 50VA 600VAC:120VAC transformer.

[image: https://www.nriparts.com/electrical/transformers/hammond/ph50aj-control-voltage-50va-600v-ac-120v-ac-transformer/]

Answer (score 3):

If any one of those transformers develops a short across its primary winding, the fault would cascade until it ate all five transformers; lose one and suddenly the remaining four would each get 150V (and get much hotter than before), so a second would fail soon afterwards. The second would fail, and now the remaining four would each get 200V. A third would fail, and the remaining two would get 300V each. Might get pretty spectacular.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly feasible to implement the series connection of the  transformers, but you should be very careful with the phase relationship.
In the diagram below, I show how the connection of the transformers must be performed, for two transformers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF8yWq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I recommend you previously Determines homopolar terminals (marked with a dot) by using an oscilloscope, entering a known signal phase and verifying it.
You must check all transformers before connecting.

**Edit:** After writing this response, I consulted with the staff of transformer test of where I work. The answer was that no matter whether the phase relationship if the transformer is single phase, since in that case there is no concatenation of magnetic flux. I can not assure this assertion. Personally I connected groups of up to three transformers as described above, and I can assure it works.

Comment: You seem very confident of what you say, but can you provide some evidence (articles), explanations or at least a "I've been doing this for decades!"? There's some 600VAC involved.

Comment: A (very very) quick look around lead me to discover that inductance and resistance of the windings are not always specified...

Comment: If he gets the phase relationship wrong, because the windings are all in series (and the transformers can be assumed to be non-magnetically connected), what is the worst that could happen?

Comment: @Andyaka, you'd lose 2x a transformer's output... one for the reversed phase, and a second one to neutralize the reversal. Your secondary would only deliver 360V instead of 600V.

Comment: Really, it isn't that big a deal. The only caveat is that the transformer *insulation* (coil-to-coil and coil-to-core) needs to be rated for the full 600V. Hook the primaries in series. Hook the secondaries in series (but don't connect them to any load). Put one lead of your AC voltmeter at the beginning of the string of secondaries, and probe each of the intermediate points with the other lead. The readings should go up in the sequence 120V, 240V, 360V, 480V and 600V. If at any point, the voltage drops instead of rising, the secondary you just passed needs to have its connections reversed.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I currently work in a factory for power transformers and rectifiers. We have sometimes made ​​such connections.

Comment: @Andyaka If the secondary windings are connected in opposing phase, their voltages are subtracted. There is even a method of line voltage regulation, which applies this principle to windings connected in series with the load.

Comment: @DaveTweed Exactly. I think your excellent contribution.

Comment: @TDHofstetter I'm perfectly aware of what actually happens - I'm trying to point out that there isn't a bad scenario - the answerer suggested "but you should be very careful with the phase relationship" as if there was some fire hazard.

Comment: @Andyaka - I think I understand what you're saying; yours was a rhetorical question, true?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work (is valid), except for the safety aspect of it.  To take care of this, you **must** add, in series with the **input** windings, a 15 ma 800V AC fuse. This will prevent a possible "runaway" condition which could destroy the transformers and possibly cause a fire or an explosion!

Answer (score 0):

With identical theoretical transformers there is no problem.

With supposedly identical real transformers there could be problems. I can envisage that the primary inductance (this drives the transformer action) could be different by up to 30% compared to another and if 4 were 15% low and 1 were 15% high, this transformer would see significantly more primary voltage when wired in series.

Think of it like 4 resistors of value 85 and one resistor of value 115 - together they add up to 455 and the fraction of voltage across the 115 resistor will be 25.3% or, as a fraction of 600 VAC, will be 157 volts. Not a vast deal more on the face of it but, if that transformer starts to saturate then it's going to get warm and may in fact burn out.

Comment: What about balancing resistors? Can that actually work?

Comment: @VladimirCravero The primary inductance might be 3 henries (because they are small transformers) and at 60 Hz this is an impedance of about 1131 ohms - think about how warm the balancing resistors are going to get. I don't think the primary inductance of a small transformer may get much above 10 henries but it's all down to what the OP is looking at - he may have something that is 30 henries but still, balancing with "R" is gonna fry-up a lot of watts LOL.

Comment: So the way to go is "use enough transformers to be safe".

Comment: @VladimirCravero - I'd match them by connecting two across 120VAC and checking the centre point is 110VAC then step and repeat to get 5 reasonably matched primaries.

Comment: I don't know why you think the characteristics would vary so much. The inductance is primarily (pun intended!) a function of the number of turns in the winding and the permeability of the core, both of which are rather tightly controlled in the manufacturing process. Also, core saturation is a function of current, and since the windings are in series, the current must be the same throughout.

Comment: Are all transformers made with a machine that counts turns, or are many of them made by turning on a machine which starts wrapping layers of wire, and turning off the machine when the wires have reached the proper thickness?  Counting turns isn't rocket science (18th-century textile-manufacturing equipment could do such things) but equipment that didn't have to keep a count could be simpler and cheaper.

Comment: @DaveTweed as I've said in another comment, a very quick search revealed that inductance is sometimes not specified, thus it is not probably well controlled... Maybe it was just an unlucky search anyway.

Comment: @supercat: They count the turns. As you say, it's easy to do, and anything else would be too uncontrolled.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: It isn't specified because most customers don't really care about the exact value. Assuming that this means it isn't well-controlled is quite a leap.

Comment: @DaveTweed well it seems legit to me to assume the opposite, i.e. if the manufacturer controls a parameter so closely that he can specify it, why not doing so? You may say that inductance is inherently closely controlled, and I can agree on that.

Comment: @DaveTweed: When layers of windings are overlaid, I would expect a certain level of randomness in exactly how they "pack".  This would in turn imply that two windings which have the same number of turns may have different lengths of wire.  Is the number of turns always the "controlled" parameter, and the length of wire just is whatever it happens to be?  If two transformers have the same number of turns, but one has an extra 0.2 ohms worth of wire, would adding a 0.2-ohm resistor in series with the first make their behaviors indistinguishable?

Comment: @supercat: Have you ever disassembled a power transformer? There really isn't any "randomness" at all. There are layers of insulation (paper or plastic film) between layers of windings that keep things rather even.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I haven't ripped apart transformers, but many of them at least from the outside don't seem to have a separator between every winding layer.  I could imagine that at higher voltages adding such separators would reduce the amount of insulation required on the winding wire, but would expect that installing it could add some costs of its own.

Comment: Andy's right. You don't design around unspecified criteria, and the variation in primary inductance between units is almost certainly going to be unspecified.